# Free Space Notifier

Tags: server, events

On my Windows machines I use Task Scheduler to perform two tasks:

- Inform me when the machine boots
- Inform me if disk space is running low

I managed the first point in ubuntu using crontab.

In windows I manage the second point using Events. I setup task scheduler so that if event 2013 triggers I send an email.

It is possible to achieve the same with Ubuntu server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some mail agent in the server (e.g. postfix)... try this

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(df --output=pcent / | grep -o '[0-9]*') -ge 80 ]]; then
  echo "You're running out of space" | mail picachu
fi
```

**df --output=pcent /** returns the free space percentage of my root file system.

**grep** strips the trailing % so **if** can compare integers.

Comment: This would go into the cron process or should I place it in a batch script and execute that from cron?

Comment: I'm not that Windows savvy but I guess the crontab solution is mostly similar to the task scheduler way. Both solutions will work; call the script via crontab or add a crontab line with minor modifications: * * * * * [ $(df --output=pcent / | grep -o '[0-9]*') -ge 10 ] && echo "Youre running out of space" | mail picachu